# How can I use .htaccess to redirect a folder on my website to a folder on another website?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to have everything in this folder on my website - http://www.mywebsite.com/media/images/* redirect to another website with the same structure i.e. http://www.theotherwebsite.com/XXX/media/images/* using .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, it can be accomplished by [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) alone, no need to use Rewrite.

```
Redirect permanent /media/images http://foobar.com/new/location
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... managed to figure this one out...

```
RewriteRule ^media/images/(.*)$ http://www.theotherwbsite.com/XXX/media/images/$1 [L]
```